# Shell script not running with Cron, but runs manually

Tags: shell, cron

I feel like I have tried everything, my search history is about 20 pages deep on google trying to fix this and nothing works. Basically I have a script that checks if my tun0 interface exists, and if it is missing, the computer will restart. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
if echo `ifconfig` | grep -q "tun0"
then echo ""
else
    reboot
fi
```

The script itself runs fine if I invoke it at a terminal  using its path:

```
/scripts/vpnrestart1.sh
```

I've added this at the top of crontab -e:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

My cron task looks like this:

```
* * * * * /scripts/vpnrestart1.sh
```

Permissions are all fine on the script itself and it can be executed without using sudo. As I mentioned, it runs from the terminal just fine and works as designed. But if I put it in cron and remove the tun0 interface, nothing ever happens.

Comment: How come the path you're running manually has a "1" in it?

Comment: It's supposed to be vpnrestart1.sh. Good catch, but that was a typo on here, not in my cron file unfortunately. I've edited the code block above.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't run?  Did you try outputting something to a file to know what actually happens?  Are you sure `reboot` works when run from that `cron`?  Why don't you use the init system to manage this VPN?

Comment: surely `/etc/profile`, not `/etc.profile`?

Comment: And you can do just `ifconfig | grep` without the echo (not that it helps with the cron, either)

Comment: @bobah, yes the .sh file says /etc/profile. Another typo on my end here. Sorry about that, it's been fixed above.

Comment: @JuliePelletier : I suppose I am assuming it's not being run because if I run the script manually the "reboot" command works like a charm. If I disconnect the vpn and then just execute the script by hand it reboots the computer as planned. But when leaving it in cron, the computer never restarts. Maybe I'm missing something in terms of cron, I haven't worked with it much so I am not very well-versed. In terms of the init system I haven't worked with that either so if you think that would be better for this task, let me know. TIA

Comment: What does the email message that `cron` sends to your user account after each invocation of the job tell you? What do the `cron` log messages (in `/var/log/`) tell you? This _is_ for a `root` account isn't it. You can't just `reboot` without some sort of root privileges...

Comment: @roaima I've found that with this VPN program it doesn't always come back if you restart the app after a crash. The cleanest solution I could come up with was to reboot the VM because it's set to autostart on boot. I can't seem to find the emails, and there's no Cron entries in /var/log..

I am logged in as myself and I'm not sudoing when I edit the crontab so I assume the jobs are being scheduled as me. But I am not sure the "reboot" command requires root because I don't sudo when I trigger the command manually from terminal either.

Comment: Run `logger 'vpnrestart got to step 1'` and look in your equivalent of `/var/log/user.log`. Once you've found where the message appears, sprinkle these messages through your short piece of code, remembering to change `step 1` each time. Typically, first line, and on either side of any `if` branch. Then look to see what it's doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43869/discussion-between-coltsfan95-and-roaima).

Comment: A common problem with jobs run in a different environment is the PATH and two commands from your script depend on it.  You should try to put the full path to both `ifconfig` and `reboot`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier would that make a difference simply because it's run in Cron? Because when I run the script manually it has no issues invoking those two commands.

Comment: Yes.  As I said, it's related to the environment variables which are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Ok, so you are saying to just fully qualify the path to those commands in the script, right?

Comment: Yes.  And if that still fails, put traces in the script like `echo restarting > /tmp/test.log` before the `reboot` and check the output.

Comment: @JuliePelletier So I changed    ifconfig     to     /sbin/ifconfig    and    reboot    to     
/sbin/reboot     and the script still works when run by hand. But cron seems to still be unable to trigger a reboot for some reason. But it looks like the cron is running the script because in my else block, above reboot, I added that log line you suggested and that log file gets created and it says "restarting." It also is getting run each minute as planned because I can see the mod time change each minute, on the minute.

Comment: Then add `id` in your script to see which user/group it executes as, and ideally redirect output from `reboot` so we can see if it gets an error message (`/sbin/reboot > /tmp/log 2>&1`).

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever try debugging your script to see what happens when executed by `cron`? Insert below code into your script:

```
# log stdout and stderr to two different files
exec >>/var/log/looog.log 2>>/var/log/looog.err.log

# ...and log every command we try to execute to stderr (aka looog.err.log)
set -x
```

Once you script is executed those two files will be generated and you will be able to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If running `reboot` directly as a non-root user works when you're logged in, it's because your system is configured to allow users who are physically logged in to reboot the system. This works via [Polkit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit).

From a crontab, you aren't in a logged-in session. A cron job that reboots the system would have to run as root.

I don't think rebooting is the solution to create a network interface. Just call whatever you do normally to bring up the VPN. And you'll probably need to be root to do that (you need to be root to set up a network interface, so either `vpnrestart1.sh` must run as root, or it gets root permissions via a setuid program such as sudo for the critical parts, or it delegates to NetworkManager which may use Polkit to allow some user sessions to affect the system configuration).

Comment: well the thing is, the VPN is set to auto-start on boot. I wasn't sure how many processes the program starts and uses to run so that's why I didn't have it re open the processes. I just triggered a reboot because I know the program will start cleanly in that case

Answer (score 1):

Use full path instead of relative path in your shell script. This solved my issue.

Comment: Cron ought to have this written in upper case, everywhere...