# crontab not running rscript

Tags: cron, r

I have this single program that doesn't run from cron (RScript). I've tried running an sh script and calling it from that. Calling it by its full path and the likes. But it won't run. Running it directly via the console (from the same user as it's croned) works fine. What could cause this, or how can I get around it?
My crontab has one line:

```
* * * * * sh /home/user/path/to/script/scriptFile.sh
```

the script file is:

```
/bin/Rscript /home/user/path/to/script/scriptFile.R
```

I've also tried having

```
cd /home/user/path/to/script/ && /bin/Rscript /home/user/path/to/script/scriptFile.R
```

As the crontab file

Comment: Hi @AdminBee. Thank you for your response. It's a fairly standard Ubuntu 20.04 (running on Oracle). What other `crontab` detail are needed?

Comment: @AdminBee Edited. Does it make more sense now?
Thank you

Comment: Try the solution in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303017/100397, which captures _stdout_ and _stderr_. Remember also that `cron` sends you a (local) email for every attempted run that results in some sort of output. You'll find them with the `mail` or `mailx` command (or `less $MAIL` if you want the direct route)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script not running with Cron, but runs manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302918/shell-script-not-running-with-cron-but-runs-manually)

Comment: @roaima you mean the first answer there? You were referring to an elevating user. I'm using it for a normal one. 
Should I put them at `~/.logs/looog.log and ~/.logs/looog.err.log` or something?

Comment: OK. I think it's some error at the application level with the script.
It's running. But only producing errors. And they go to `looog.err.log` :)

Comment: Great, so you're on your way to fixing the problem, yes?

Comment: Yeah. I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Running Rscript from cron seems to have `libPaths` wrong - It seems to have other environment variables all toogether. This primarily messes up loading libraries.
You can either install packages system-wide for R. Or use `.libPaths()` at the start of the script, pointing it to where it should take the packages from.